# CSS transition Not Working on box-shadow Property

Tags: focus, transition, css

I have an input text field an I would like that when a user focuses on it, the box-shadow property transitions from one style to a different style. What is wrong with my two CSS declarations causing the transition not to happen?

```
input[type="text"], textarea { box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) inset; transition: box-shadow 0.33s ease-in-out; }
input[type="text"]:focus, textarea:focus { box-shadow: 0 0 7px 0 rgba(30, 144, 255, 1); }
```

Comment: Does anything happen AT ALL when you focus and unfocus?

Comment: No, nothing happens at all with the transition. Sure, the box-shadow changes, but it changes immediately, without a transition.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems that you can't transition from an inset box-shadow to a normal box-shadow, and vice versa.  Here is a great answer [CSS box-shadow transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22446148/css-box-shadow-transition).   And applied to your code:

```
input[type="text"], textarea { box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) inset, 0px 0px 0px white; transition: box-shadow 0.33s ease-in-out; }
input[type="text"]:focus, textarea:focus { box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px white inset, 0 0 7px 0 rgba(30, 144, 255, 1); }
```

I tested in Chrome and it works perfectly.

**edit:**

For further explanation, basically you are creating an empty / blank style (0px 0px 0px white) for the inset box-shadow on the :focus class, and an empty outer box-shadow style for the not :focus class.  This way the inset shadow transitions from styled to non-styled and the outer shadow transitions from non-styled to styled. Hopefully that clarifies a bit.

Comment: Works great, and extra points for the explanation. The only change I did was instead of the color "white," I used "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)," which is black but with zero opacity, that way, it's transparent and I don't have to worry about matching the page's background color.